# Reminder notification with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, sidekiq

i am new in ROR and i am using 'Sidekiq' for scheduling Reminders. i can schedule reminder jobs/messages successfully through "Sidekiq". Here is code of 'reminder.rb'

```
 class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :status_value 
  belongs_to :communication


   after_create :add_sidekiq_job

  # before_destroy :remove_sidekiq_job

  def add_sidekiq_job
    id = ReminderWorker.perform_at(scheduled_at, {id: self.id.to_s})
    # self.update_attributes(job_id: id)
  end

  def remove_sidekiq_job
    queue =  Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
    job = queue.find_job(self.job_id)
    job.delete if job
  end

  def scheduled_at

    self.notification_time.to_time.to_i - Time.now.to_i
  end

end
```

and here is code of 'reminderworker.rb' where i can get 'reminder/notification message' by passing the id.

```
class ReminderWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(args)
    reminder = Reminder.find(args['id'])
    puts "~~~~~Notificaiton~~~~~~~~"
  end
end
```

Everything is working till now but now i want to show notification message (which i can get from 'reminder = Reminder.find(args['id'])') in my notification page . how i can do this?

Comment: In perform action create a notification in database with the message from the reminder object, and check from the front end for new notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show this message on user's page you should use some kind of persisted pub/sub client-server connection, that will be available in sidekiq. In Rails 5 it could be [ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable), in previous versions of Rails - [Faye](https://github.com/faye/faye) or something like this.

Comment: kimrgrey, is it possible to do it without Faya?

Comment: Well, there a lot of methods how to implement client-server interaction. But if I'm right and you want to push reminder from sidekiq to subscribed user's page then you need some kind of connection between sidekiq and browser. Take a look on this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub. May be it will clarify a problem.